# Validating form with unpoly

Tags: forms, validation, unpoly

I' trying to validate a form with unpoly. Here my HTML:

```
        <div>
            <label for="salesrepresentative-name">Name: </label><br/>
            <input id="salesrepresentative-name" name="name" up-validate=".name-errors"/>
            <span class="name-errors"></span>
        </div>
```

And the error message what i get is:

```
Could not find failure target in response (tried [".name-errors", "body"])
```

Any ideas, what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[`up-validate`](https://unpoly.com/up-validate) will submit the form and replace your current `<span class="name-errors">` with the same span from the response.

The error message you received means that the form submission did not include a `<span class="name-errors">`. If even did not include a `<body>` tag (which Unpoly uses as a fallback when selectors are missing).

Try to submit the form without Unpoly and see if the response is what you're expecting.